# How get a value of an empty_value in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a list for `multiple choices`. When user do not choice any choice should display `ALL` the information concerned of articles.
I added a default value `ALL` in my `form` this following:

```
   <?php

    $user = $app['security']->getToken()->getUser();
            $default = 'ALL';
            $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form',['lru' => [$default]])->setMethod('GET')
 ->add('lru', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array(
                     $default => $default,

                    '\'ATSU\'' => 'ATSU', .... )

                    'required' => FALSE,
                    'empty_value' => 'ALL',
                    'empty_data' => NULL,
                    'multiple' => TRUE
                      ))
```

When I run it shown an error, I should modify my request to take a `empty_value` `ALL` per default:

I declared in my class:

```
 private $_sqlSelect = 'Select * ';
  private $_sqlFrom = 'From `piecearticles`';
  private $_sqlWhere = 'Where ';
```

And this following my function:

```
if ($this->_count == 0) {
        $this->_sqlWhere.="`piecearticles`.`ID_Article`=`article`.`ID_Article` AND `piecearticles`.`Designiation`=`article`.`Designiation` AND `article`.`ID_LRU`=`lru`.`ID_LRU`";

        $this->_count++;
    } else {
        $this->_sqlWhere.="AND `piecearticles`.`ID_Article`=`article`.`ID_Article` AND `piecearticles`.`Designiation`=`article`.`Designiation` AND `article`.`ID_LRU`=`lru`.`ID_LRU`";
    }

    if (!empty($this->_lru)) {
        if(is_array($this->_lru) or ($this->_lru instanceof Traversable)) {
            $this->_sqlWhere.=" AND `lru`.`LRU` IN (" . implode(",", $this->_lru) . ")"; //='" . $this->_lru . "'";
        } else {
            $this->_sqlWhere.=" AND `lru`.`LRU`='" . $this->_lru . "'";
        }
    }
    //if (strpos($this->_sqlFrom,'article') == false) {
    $this->_sqlFrom.=', `article` ';
    //}
    if (strpos($this->_sqlFrom, 'lru') == false) {
        $this->_sqlFrom.=',`lru`';
    }
    //echo count($this->_lru);
}
```

I did an `echo` of my `query`, it return `lru`.`LRU` IN (ALL)`
How can I change my request to take a value per default 'ALL'.
Thank you.

Comment: Your information provided leaves more questions than answers. E.g. where is `$this->_sqlFrom` initialized? Regarding 'ALL' : you usally implement this by omitting the corresponding WHERE clause.

Comment: @Adder I initialized the _sqlForm in my class (I changed my question above).

Comment: For which field do you want to select ALL of them? There is a problem in your code, This is not used consistently `$this->_sqlWhere.="AND` and also, no `AND` is needed if it is the first one added to the where clause. That is why I often start my where clauses with `WHERE 1=1 `.

Comment: I have 5 other fields,  when user do not select this field do return ALL, another information this field was an input then I changed it to list for multiple choices. How can change my request please to be compatible with the researchs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll venture to provide a partial example which I hope adresses your issue for one column. I am assuming the user either checks just the 'ALL' box, or selects several other boxes.

```
if (!empty($this->_lru)) {
        if((is_array($this->_lru) or ($this->_lru instanceof Traversable)) && ! in_array('ALL', $this->_lru)) {
            $this->_sqlWhere.=" AND `lru`.`LRU` IN (" . implode(",", $this->_lru) . ")"; //='" . $this->_lru . "'";
        } else if ($this->_lru != 'ALL' && ! in_array('ALL', $this->_lru)) {
            $this->_sqlWhere.=" AND `lru`.`LRU`='" . $this->_lru . "'";
        }
    }
```

This snippet should achieve the following: If no box is selected at all, treat it as a query for all. If any box for 'ALL' is selected, omit the where clause. otherwise if the `_lru` is an array, implode the array into a where clause. If, for reasons I do not understand, the `_lru` is not an array, use its value in the where clause.